# Adding preference buttons to main nav that persist via user sessions. (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, session

I would prefer not installing a plugin to achieve this and I don't mind coding something myself.
I'm simply unsure of the "wordpress-y" way to go about it.

So here goes,
Each one of the products has four variations, always the same, they are the region selection and the prices are different based on those.

However, I would like to have a dropdown in the main nav of the site where customers can specify what variation (region) price is displayed across the site for the whole duration of their session.

So it's a two-part thing, I would like to know the ideal method of saving this user preference in the $_SESSION (I'm assuming) and then retrieving this information when displaying prices by variation, I already have a hook to handle that in the category pages but at the moment it defaults to just a hardcoded region, instead it should be user preference OR default of america.

This information does not need to be persisted to disk or DB, it can just be in the session.

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if anything needs clarification.

/edit
Just noticed the wc offtopic tag, but although yes it's somewhat related to woocommerce, storing a value in the user session isn't a wc specific thing at all. It's a user session question, wc is just framing for the use case.

Comment: Most WP hosts do not support `$_SESSION`, it also isn't a way to get around cookies as the session ID is stored in a cookie, which is also a security issue. WordPress itself does not use PHP sessions.

Comment: @TomJNowell Ok no problem, I really have no attachment to $_SESSION either way. What is the mechanism I would use then? Clearly wordpress has a way of keeping track of users and their information.

Comment: The same way every other site does, cookies! Users sessions in WP are cookie based. Think about it, how does a site that's not built with PHP do it if there are no PHP sessions

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes of course, but are there really no pre-defined places (via cookies or not) that let me keep track of what guest/user has selected? Like cart for example, I know I don't directly edit the cookies, I would use built in WC methods for that. Is there something similar for navigation state / menus?

Comment: you'd need to create/update/read that cookie yourself, in JS/PHP/both. If WC provides a mechanism that's great but you would need to ask in a WC forum or community or via their official support as 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here. WP provides no state management for cookies/sessions other than are you or are you not logged in, the closest is user meta for logged in users. The part of your Q where you change the variations/prices based on the cookie is definitely off-topic and outside this stacks scope. I wouldn't build this into a WP nav menu

Comment: the frontend part that sets the cookie requires almost no WP knowledge at all to construct, just generic JS/PHP to create the control, the part that requires more in depth knowledge is how to control WooCommerce to change the products available

Comment: @TomJNowell I know how to set a cookie and read it, I also know how to change the products by this value, I have a filter set up for it. I'm just not familiar with wordpress and where I'd add the select I want for the nav menu and then what file would be handling the request, or if I just use functions.php? Or I use ajax? So far I think the best way from functions would be to add a shortcode that contains the select (form) and have a hook to handle it also in functions.php to set the cookie.

Comment: you'd find the place in your theme where you want it to appear and you would write your code there. Or you could build a widget, or a block, or a shortcode, etc, there is no canonical single golden path here